# Multidimensional array from arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find out how to make a 2D array out of possibly normal arrays.
Here is an example how'd I imagine that:

```
int[,] original = new int[,] {{1,1,1,1}, {1,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,1}, {1,1,1,1}};

int[] part = {1,1,1,1};
int[,] copy = new int[,] {part}, {1,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,1}, {1,1,1,1}};
```

Comment: what you tried so far? Can you show us your attempt? where did you stuck? is there any error? if yes then please add it in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not easy to do in general with native 2d arrays, and impossible to do during initialization.

But you can modify an existing 2d array with the following extension methods.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[,] original = new int[,] { 
            { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
            { 1, 0, 0, 1 }, 
            { 1, 0, 0, 1 }, 
            { 1, 1, 1, 1 } };

        int[] row_0 = original.GetRow(0);
        // {1,1,1,1}

        int[] part = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        original.SetRow(0, part);
        // {{1,2,3,4},{1,0,0,1},...}
    }

    public static T[] GetRow<T>(this T[,] matrix, int row)
    {
        int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int columns = matrix.GetLength(1);
        T[] result = new T[columns];
        if (row<=rows)
        {
            int size = Buffer.ByteLength(matrix)/rows;
            Buffer.BlockCopy(matrix, row*size, result, 0, size);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void SetRow<T>(this T[,] matrix, int row, params T[] elements)
    {
        int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int columns = matrix.GetLength(1);
        if (row<rows && elements.Length == columns)
        {
            int size = Buffer.ByteLength(elements);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(elements, 0, matrix, row*size, size);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the same functionality is trivial with jagged arrays. Instead of `int[,]` use `int[][]`.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[][] original = new int[][] {
            new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 1 },
            new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 1 },
            new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
        };

        int[] row_0 = original[0];
        // { 1, 1, 1, 1}
        int[] parts = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // implicit int[] type

        original[0] = parts;
        // { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 0, 1},..}
        int[,] matrix = original.JaggedToMatrix();            
    }

    public static T[,] JaggedToMatrix<T>(this T[][] jagged)
    {
        int rows = jagged.Length;
        int columns = jagged.Length>0 ? jagged[0].Length : 0;

        T[,] result = new T[rows, columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            result.SetRow(i, jagged[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static T[][] MatrixToJagged<T>(this T[,] matrix)
    {
        int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int columns = matrix.GetLength(1);

        T[][] result = new T[rows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            result[i] = matrix.GetRow(i);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static T[] GetRow<T>(this T[,] matrix, int row)
    {
        int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int columns = matrix.GetLength(1);
        T[] result = new T[columns];
        if (row<=rows)
        {
            int size = Buffer.ByteLength(matrix)/rows;
            Buffer.BlockCopy(matrix, row*size, result, 0, size);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void SetRow<T>(this T[,] matrix, int row, params T[] elements)
    {
        int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int columns = matrix.GetLength(1);
        if (row<rows && elements.Length == columns)
        {
            int size = Buffer.ByteLength(elements);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(elements, 0, matrix, row*size, size);
        }
    }
}
```